# Should it create new database for phpbb?

Tags: phpbb3

I have site with database. I want to add forum phpbb to mysite. com/forum. Should it create new database for forum or its better to use one database for whole site?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new database and a new database user for phpBB. This makes the data structure more organized and that helps when making backups. Also, if one of your softwares gets hacked, at least your other database is safe.